# Mouse flickering on one monitor

Tags: nvidia, mouse, monitor

I've done quite a bit of googling to find a solution to this but couldn't find anything. I have two monitors, an LG one and a Samsung one and my mouse disappears and flickers on the Samsung one. Also I'm using a Logitech Preformance MX mouse. I just freshly installed the latest LTS version of Ubuntu. I have two Nvidia Gefore GTX470 graphics cards and one monitor is plugged into each of them. I heard about a fix with an Unknown monitor showing up in the display setting but I'm not seeing that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: I've tried to change the drivers I've using, it's fixed the flickering but my second monitor is nolonger recognized. :(

Answer (score 0):

The second GeForce card cannot be used to run a second monitor using the newer NVidia drivers (this has nothing to do with Ubuntu but with NVidia itself.)

There are ways around that, but they're all ugly (and complicated).

You can still use the secondary card using CUDA for video rendering, FPU computation, ...

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...*